# editing a live video using php

Tags: php, video, facebook-apps

I want to build an **facebook application** using which i will show a advertisement video shot by advertisement company on the facebook page and in that video at specific place i want to show the logged user's profile pic.

Explaining more...it will be an live video (not the one created by graphics) where  one or two place i will show the logged user profile picture for example if two people are talking and one is having a phone then at that phone i will show logged user profile pic.

can any body please give me any idea how i can achieve this ?

**i know following things.**

1. making a facebook application
2. embedding a video in it.
3. fetching the logged in user information like profile pic and all.

**I need help with following.**

How to edit a video and show the fetched profile picture in the particular place of that video. ??

thanks,

Comment: this is fairly creepy

Answer (score 0):

php cant edit videos. Maybe you can try to [run an commandline programm from php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) like [avisynth](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/Main_Page) or ffmpeg to genreate the video withou php.